# How to plot roc curve of Logistic Regression model if the weight of classes are different

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, roc

I always got the same ROC value (0.81) no matter how the class_weight and confusion matrix change.
How to plot and get the correct ROC,AUC value?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

logmodel = LogisticRegression(solver ='liblinear',class_weight = {0:0.02,1:1})
#logmodel = LogisticRegression(solver ='liblinear')
logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions = logmodel.predict(X_test)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions))
print(classification_report(y_test,predictions))
acc = accuracy_score(y_test,predictions)

print ('accuracy_score =%.3f' %(acc))

#y_score = logmodel.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)
model_probs = logmodel.predict_proba(X_test)
y_score = model_probs[:, 1]
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, y_score)
auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_score)

plt.plot(fpr, tpr, marker='.', label= 'ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % auc)
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post code which shows how exactly `class_weight` and `confusion matrix` (or accuracy?) change. Until now, your code is correct, I do not see any error in it.